How to read from specific event hub partition spark-streaming fabric
I have a event hub with 32 partition .
I need to read from Partition 1 from Event hub using Pyspark .
This is my existing code
# Config
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://abcd"
eventHubName = "event_hub"

ehConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString),
  'eventhubs.eventHubName': eventHubName
}
df_stream  = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs")\
  .options(**ehConf)\
  .option("compression", "gzip") \
  .load() 

Please suggest how can we read .
I can read from specific partition in EventHub SDK but not in Pyspark .
I was not able to find any config in docs also
https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/eventhubs/EventHubsConf.scala

This should work
df_stream  = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs")\
  .options(**ehConf)\
  .option("partitionId", 1)\
  .load() 


Even though I am writing to different partition it goes into Same other partition
